# How to get user profile in for in facebook?

Tags: facebook

How can I get profile information in facebook according to emailid using an API?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access Facebook information by querying according to an email address. It is not an indexable field. There is NO way to get Facebook user information using an email address. You must use name or username

Answer (score 1):

The email fiel is **NOT indexable**.

That means you can not search for a profile by using the email field (That would be a privacy issue).

You can take a look here to get more details:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

Answer (score 0):

The facebook API, are well documented: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Answer (score 0):

If you can read Java go through this nice [tutorial](http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/06/implementing-facebook-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-java/) on accessing Facebook after authenticating using OAuth. It includes a basic example of fetching an user's profile details.